# Regex to capture all text after 4 consecutive capital letters observed

Tags: python, regex

EDIT: The regex should **not** look for LONDON (it could be PARIS, BELGIUM etc.).. it should be flexible so that it matches any article when it observes **4 consecutive capital letters**.

for the following text:

```
    text text text, more text

   -- Some More Texty Text Text
      better manage their online privacy needs

   -- Another line of Text
      in foster programs

LONDON, UK. January 28, 2019--

More example of text, lots of text, Text text. Imagine this is a long article... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
```

I would like a regex that could basically extract all text from the **LONDON** line and thereon (the regex logic should identify this line when it observes for or more capital letters). So the output should be:

```
LONDON, UK. January 28, 2019--

More example of text, lots of text, Text text. Imagine this is a long article... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
```

Comment: why not just `split` it? `print s.split("LONDON",1)[1]`

Comment: This `(?s)[A-Z]{4}.*` should work [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9EbrN/1)

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh, looks like it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:LONDON).*
```

The above would grab the word `LONDON` and everything afterwards.

```
import re
pattern = r'(?:LONDON).*'
function_string = "text text text, more text -- Some More Texty Text Text better manage their online privacy needs  -- Another line of Text in foster programs  LONDON, UK. January 28, 2019-- More example of text, lots of text, Text text. Imagine this is a long article... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah."

print(re.findall(pattern, function_string))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['LONDON, UK. January 28, 2019-- More example of text, lots of text, Text text. Imagine this is a long article... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.']
```

**EDIT:**

Perks of over-reading, what you need is:

```
pattern = r'(?s)[A-Z]{4}.*'
```

As suggested by @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi in the comments already.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general approach, try:

```
 import re

 four_caps = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{4}.*')
 string = "text text text, more text -- Some More Texty Text Text better manage their online privacy needs  -- Another line of Text in foster programs  LONDON, UK. January 28, 2019-- More example of text, lots of text, Text text. Imagine this is a long article... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah."

 output = re.findall(four_caps, string)
```

Comment: I tried this, but doesn't work properly, I think this matches incorrectly because it doesnt look for 4 consecutive occurrences but rather just 4 occurrences.

Comment: @JayjayJay did you try the exact regex above?  Or did you use the one posted by user5173426?  the one above should only match 4 consecutive caps letters, where as the addition of the `(?s)` regex will look for any occurrence of 4 caps in a string.